# Cómo obtener las clases del módulo actual desde una de las clases

Tags: python

Hago algo parecido a lo siguiente para conocer y filtrar las clases que tengo declaradas en un módulo:

```
class Padre:
    None

class Hijo(Padre):
    None

c = dir()
for element in c:
    if issubclass(eval(element), Padre):
        print (element) 

# Padre
# Hijo
```

Pero lo que necesito es hacer esto desde dentro de una de las clases. Algo parecido a lo siguiente pero que funcione. Porque de esta forma lo único que obtengo es el atributo `__dir__` del tipo de texto `'__main__'`.

```
class Padre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = self.obtenSubClases()

    def obtenSubClases(self):
        l = []
        c = (dir(self.__module__))
        for element in c:
            if issubclass(eval(element), Padre):
                l.append(element)
        return l

class Hijo(Padre):
    None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estos menesteres te aconsejo usar el módulo `inspect` y el método [inspect.getmembers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers):

```
import sys
import inspect

class Padre:

    def __init__(self):
        self.h = self.obten_sub_clases()

    @classmethod
    def obten_sub_clases(cls):
        filtro = lambda obj: inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, cls)
        subclases = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], filtro)
        return [subclase[1] for subclase in subclases]


class Hijo(Padre):
    pass


class Nieto(Hijo):
    pass

class Otra():
    pass
```

La propia clase Padre también es retornada, si no la queremos en la lista podemos hacer:

```
filtro = lambda obj: obj != cls and inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, cls)
```

En Python 3 y clases de nuevo estilo de Python 2 (derivan de `Object`) tenemos también el atributo especial `__subclasses__` que nos permite obtener las subclases directas de una clase determinada.

```
class Padre:

    def __init__(self):
        self.h = self.obten_sub_clases()

    @classmethod
    def obten_sub_clases(cls):
        res = set()
        que = set()
        que.update(cls.__subclasses__())
        while que:
            res.update(que)
            subcls = que.pop().__subclasses__()
            que.update(subcls)
        return [c for c in res if c.__module__ == __name__]
```

En Python >= 3.6 podemos sobreescribir el método `__init__subclass`, el cual es ejecutado cuando se hereda de la clase a cualquier nivel y usarlo para crear la lista de subclases dinámicamente:

```
class Padre:
    subclases = []

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclases.append(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        self.h = self.obten_sub_clases()

    @classmethod
    def obten_sub_clases(cls):
        return [subclase  for subclase in cls.subclases if subclase.__module__ == __name__]
```

En todos los casos el método es un método de clase, lo que implica que puede ser llamado usando la clase, sin necesidad de una instancia de `Padre`:

```
Padre.obten_sub_clases()
```